# Cannot send HTTP request to another docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, httprequest, microservices

When I try to send HTTP request from one container to another I get

*(Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException*

I am sure the cause of the error is an invalid address. Though I have checked similar issues I wasn't able to fix it myself.

Dockerfile of mainApp (the one which sends requests)

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/mainApp.war mainApp.war
EXPOSE 8078
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "mainApp.war"]
```

Here I make the request

```
String pepAddress =  "http://microservice3:8080";

public ResponseEntity<String> getUser() {

       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1080));
        requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(pepAddress + "/getUser")
                .queryParam("userId","1");

        HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate
                .exchange(builder.toUriString(),
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            httpEntity,
                            String.class);
        return result;
    }
```

SecondApp Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/PEP.war PEP.war
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "PEP.war"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  microservice1:
    image: mainapp
    expose:
      - 8078
    networks:
      - test

  microservice3:
    image: pep
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - test

networks:
  test: 
    external: true
```

Comment: check the other server code. make sure you are binding not to 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1', this is a common mistake everyone makes.

Comment: the other server seems to be fine. there's not such bindings there at all

Comment: `Connection refused` means you are hitting a server which refuses your request, right?.  What is the other server code? can you share some code to see how microservice3 code looks like?

Comment: I edited my issue, the cause of the error is because of proxy

Comment: have you also checked `external: true` property on networks. normally network is optional unless you have multiple networks. not sure where you deploy. Using a proxy like in that code is not at all a good idea. anyway, use it if you like.

Comment: Why using proxy like this is a bad idea? What approach is better?

Comment: When you write "127.0.0.1" for the proxy, you mean your host that is listening on 1080? If that is so I can write you a solution that works. However, I agree with the others that is not the best solution to connect a container to a process running on the host.